# Ps2pdf bug? The pdf output is rotated relative to the ps output

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, postscript, typesetting

I am having a bizarre problem in converting postscript to pdf using ps2pdf.  Here is a minimal code snippet that causes the problem.

```
/Times findfont 40 scalefont setfont
-1 1 scale
15 15 moveto (R) show
```

This should show the letter, horizontally reflected.  And when I view the postscript, that's what I see.  But if I take the code above, save it as a file "bad.ps" and run the following command on it

```
ps2pdf bad.ps
```

I get a *vertically* reflected letter R.

I get the same problem with other fonts.  BUT when I just draw lines, etc., the problem goes away.  Any ideas?

Comment: note you are also drawing off page (in negatve page space).  Properly to draw a backwards R at page 15 15 you need :  -1 1 scale -30 15 moveto (R) show - and with that I reproduce your unexpected 180 rotation.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like the orientation of the PDF is rotated.  By default, PS2PDF detects the orientation based on the dominant text orientation on the page.  To override this behavior, use the

`-dAutoRotatePages=/None`

command line option.  This option is described in more detail on the [PS2PDF command line reference](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Ps2pdf.htm#Orientation).

Comment: confirm this works (With the -30 mod in my other comment). I'd still flag this a bug, by what logic does the code decide upsidedown is better than backwards?

Comment: Its  a heuristic, it tries to get text to go left->right, sometimes it gets it wrong, heuristics do that.

Comment: Still I think if you don't want to have pages rotated, use the settings (and accept it as a valid answer).